# Constant Errors from Data Loader when inserting Leads

Tags: apex

I created a trigger that fires before a new lead with the goal being able to prevent duplicate leads from being entered in the system based on the company name field. When I use data loader to load the leads,some leads come in, but I also get a specific error over and over no matter how I structure my code.

The error message is: Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires that some subset of rows save without any errors in order to avoid inconsistent side effects from those triggers. Number of retries: 2

**What specifically do I need to change in my class to prevent this error from happening when using Data Loader?**  I understand why it's happening based on documentation on the salesforce site, or at least I think I do, but I do not know how to fix it in the code.

```
public with sharing class LeadAction {


    // check for duplicate leads
    public static void checkDuplicateLeads(list<Lead> leads) {

        map<string,Lead> leadMap = new map<string,Lead>();


        for( Lead newLead : leads ) {
            if( newLead.Company != null) {
                leadMap.put(newLead.Company, newLead);
            }
        }

        for( Lead alead : [SELECT Id, Email, Company, FirstName, LastName FROM Lead WHERE Company in :leadMap.keyset()] ) {
            if( leadMap.containsKey(alead.Company)) {
                        leadMap.get(aLead.Company).addError('A lead already exists with this name.');
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your default batch size for the Dataloader?  I've seen issues with Trigger.new sizes fighting with the dataloader batch size.  Try reducing the default batch size in the Dataloader settings to <200 and see if you get errors?

Comment: Have you considered OOB de-duplication? Far simpler than writing triggers.

Comment: (1) Your trigger handler doesn't deal with the situation of duplicates intra-batch, only compares current batch against Leads previously saved (2) Since `Company` is a required field on Lead, checking for null Company serves no purpose

Comment: The default batch size is currently 200 @HomerJ.   I agree with OOB de-duplication Adrian Larson, but currently don't have budget for a paid tool just yet.   Crop1645 - Would you mind providing code to support your comment around not dealing with the records intra-batch?

Comment: @crop1645 - The null company field check would provide a purpose if a user tried to load a csv file and this field was omitted.  It would skip that row and not add it to the map I believe.  So true, the Company field is required on the Lead Object, but there isn't a guarantee that field will be present if a user uses Data Loader to insert records unless my thinking is off

Comment: Are you calling this `before insert` or `after insert`? Also, is company name really the unique identifier for a lead? That seems... unlikely that there should only ever exist one lead per Company.

Comment: but a null company would never match an existing company in the database so the soql query will not find it anyway